# Blazor: Search Box Not Searching On First Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

I just created a little search box in my Blazor application and it's doing something unexpected and I am unable to see in the Project where the issue could be. I have setup logging with Serilog to get an idea of what's happening.

Below is the informational logging for the search box.

```
[10:59:48 INF] [Shared\SearchBox.razor:Enter()] Search for null completed
[10:59:50 INF] [Shared\SearchBox.razor:Enter()] Search for Test completed
[10:59:54 INF] [Shared\SearchBox.razor:Enter()] Search for Test completed
[10:59:59 INF] [Shared\SearchBox.razor:Enter()] Search for  completed
```

The process I went through for this is by initially typing in `Test`. The first log with `Test` inputted didn't search and instead resulted in `null`. The second time I hit enter with `Test` in the search box it returned the items appropriately.

Now that the search was completed, I cleared out the search box and hit enter to get the full list again. The first time I hit enter with an empty search box (the third log), the console registered that I was searching for `Test` again. I had to hit enter a second time to search an empty box and resulting in the full list.

This seems like it may be an input validation issue but I'm not seeing where that issue lies within the Project.

SearchBox.razor:

```
@typeparam TEntity
@using Serilog

<input class="form-control" style="max-width:600px" placeholder="Search..." @onkeydown="@Enter" @bind="searchItem" />


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<TEntity> Items { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnSearch { get; set; }

    private string? searchItem;

    private async Task OnSearchClicked()
    {
        await OnSearch.InvokeAsync(searchItem);
    }

    public async Task Enter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
        {
            Log.Information("[Shared\\SearchBox.razor:Enter()] Search for {@searchItem} completed", searchItem);
            await OnSearch.InvokeAsync(searchItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Licenses.razor(where the search box is accessed):

```
@page "/licenses"
@using static HuntressAPI

<h3>Licenses</h3>

<p>Shows the current licensing count of the services</p>

<div class="w-100">
    <SearchBox Items="@Organizations" OnSearch="UpdateFilteredOrganizations"></SearchBox>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Site Name</th>
            <th>Huntress</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Organizations != null)
        {
            @foreach (var organization in _filteredOrganizations.OrderBy(a => a.Name))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@organization.Name</td>
                    <td>@organization.agents_count</td>
                    <!-- Add other columns as needed -->
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@inject HuntressAPI HuntressAPI
@code {
    private List<Organization>? Organizations { get; set; }
    private List<Organization> _filteredOrganizations { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Organizations = await HuntressAPI.Huntress();
        _filteredOrganizations = Organizations.ToList();
    }

    void UpdateFilteredOrganizations(string searchTerm)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            _filteredOrganizations = Organizations.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            _filteredOrganizations = Organizations
                .Where(org => org.Name.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that @onkeydown executes before the values is actually changes. You can try something like this:

```cs
<input class="form-control" style="max-width:600px" placeholder="Search..." @onchange=@Change />


@code {

    public async Task Change(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var yourValue = args.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be a little confused on this. In your input you took out the `Enter` class so it won't actually search for any items.

Comment: It was minimalistic example, you can add `await OnSearch.InvokeAsync((string?)args.Value);` inside `Change` method